# How do I use GrailsApplicationCommand with the gradle wrapper in an angular project?

Tags: angular, grails, gradle, gradlew, grails-3.3

In my grails angular project, I have a `GrailsApplicationCommand` which I want to run within the `server` project.

I am able to execute the command from the `server` working directory using the grails CLI:

`grails run-command my-command`

I want to use the gradle wrapper so I can execute the command on the automated build server without worrying about which Grails version the server has installed.

I tried several variants of the gradlew command, but I can't figure out one that works. I think that Grails can't find the `GrailsApplicationCommand` because it's not in the same Gradle project as the gradle wrapper itself.

What is the correct syntax to execute a command in a subproject using `gradlew`?

**Update:**

The following did not work (Command not found error):

```
example> gradlew server:runCommand -Pargs="myExample"
```

I verified that the following works:

```
example/server> grails run-command my-example
```

I am using Grails 3.3.0.M2

Comment: I updated my answer with a working command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows how to run a command with Gradle

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-command.html

So to execute that task on the `server` subproject:

`./gradlew server:runCommand -Pargs="myCommand"`

EDIT: The following works with your example

`./gradlew server:runCommand -Pargs="my-example"`

Comment: Thanks for your post! However, this syntax didn't work for me. I updated the question and created a simple sample project to rep the issue:
https://github.com/rmorrise/example